# How to make "sub-variables" in Python? (position.x, position.y, position.z)

Tags: python, list, variables

How do I make "sub-variables" in Python?
Basically what I want to do is have a class which has variable, which returns values like list, but if I do `var.subvar` it's gonna return just one of the values from the list.
Example:

```
class Object:
  
  def _init_(self, x, y, z):
    self.position.x = x #Sets sub-variables 
    self.position.y = y 
    self.position.z = z

  #Functions

object = Object(5, 3, 1)

print(object.position) #Should print out 5, 3, 1
print(object.position.y) #Should print out 3
```

I know that I could use functions or dictionaries, but is there any other way without using any brackets?

I tried setting the variable names to `var.subvar`, but it wasn't that effective and I am looking for something more effective, if anything like that exists.

Comment: "wasn't that effective": what does this mean?

Comment: I can't recall the exact way, but maybe using something like [`__repr__`](https://codedamn.com/news/python/what-is-repr-in-python) will be what others suggest

Comment: Two advices regarding your code: 1. it's `__init__`, not `_init_` 2. Don't call your variables with existing built-ins or keywrods (eg. `object`).

Comment: Define a class for your `position` variable w/ the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone suggested in the comments you can do it creating another class called Position. I added the `__str__` so when you print `object.position` is gonna print the actual values and not the class object. Remember that you need the double underscore for `__init__` and similar.

```
class Object:

  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.position = Position(x, y, z)

  #Functions

class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z}"
   
obj = Object(5, 3, 1)

print(obj.position) #Should print out 5, 3, 1
print(obj.position.y) #Should print out 3
```

As the comment below pointed out one could nest the Position class inside if it is only needed in the class `Object` writing something like

```
class Object:

    class Position:
        def __init__(self, x, y, z):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z}"

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.position = self.Position(x, y, z)

  #Functions
   
obj = Object(5, 3, 1)

print(obj.position) #Should print out 5, 3, 1
print(obj.position.y) #Should print out 3
```

and be careful with naming, `object` and other existing keywords should be avoided

Comment: This would be my approach. Only change I'd make is nesting `Class Position` within `Object` (and renaming Object to a anything but that). This will also require one to change `Position()` to `self.Position()`. This approach keeps the subclass within its relevant scope.

Comment: Yeah the `Object` name should be changed, I kept it the same just for clarity with the original question. The nesting also makes sense to keep a cleaner code, I will edit to answer to add that

Answer (score 2):

Start with creating a Position class with the behavior you want:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

This will let you access x, y and z attributes of the object. In order to define how an object is printed, you need to define its `__repr__` - method that returns a string representation of the object.

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return ", ".join(str(i) for i in [self.x, self.y, self.z])
```

You can test the object:

```
position = Position(5, 3, 1)
print(position)   # 5, 3, 1
print(position.x) # 5
```

You can see that it works like you want `object.position` to work, so now just assign it to it.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.position = Position(x, y, z)
o = Object(5, 3, 1)
```

(Alternatively, you could make a constructor that accepts position object directly:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = position
o = Object(position)
```

Both of those will end up with the same behaviour:

```
print(o.position) #Should print out 5, 3, 1
print(o.position.y) #Should print out 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Class `Point` to act like this :

```py
class Point3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.coord = [x, y, z]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.coord)

class Object:

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.position = Point3D(x, y, z)


object = Object(5, 3, 1)

print(object.position)  # Should print out 5, 3, 1
print(object.position.y)  # Should print out 3
```